# textView inside bottoSheet doesn't change

Tags: android, textview, buttonclick, settext, bottom-sheet

I try to change textView text every time i click my marker. But the the textView doesn't change the text. The log shows the text but the setText
doesn't work

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    Halte h = arrayListHalte.get(Integer.parseInt(marker.getSnippet()));
    Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClick: " + h.getNamaHalte());
    tvNamaHalte.setText(h.getNamaHalte());

    mBottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    fab.hide();
    return false;
}
```

this is my oncreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    tvNamaHalte = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama_bs);// i get my textView from bottomSheet


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code as follows and try...

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
Halte h = arrayListHalte.get(Integer.parseInt(marker.getSnippet()));
Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerClick: " + h.getNamaHalte());
mBottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
tvNamaHalte.setText(h.getNamaHalte());
fab.hide();
return false;
```

}